# Stuck in Network azure-iot-edge-dev is external, skipping

Tags: azure-iot-hub, azure-iot-edge

Runing the Build and Run Iot Edge Solution in Simulator stopped working suddenly, and the log builds the containers and stops at this message `Network azure-iot-edge-dev is external, skipping` Everything was working fine 5mins ago, tried rebooting, restarting docker, iotedgehubdev, but in vain. Do you know how can I get more logs and/or resolve this problem ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a generic error that is thrown for a variety of reasons.
Possible causes can be:

- Proxy blocking pulling images of edgeHub and edgeAgent
- A problem in the deployment.template.json (or debug template), e.g. missing brackets
- Ports of edgeHub that are in use
- Docker configured for Windows containers when targeting Linux or visa-versa

The Build output or IoT hub output in Visual Studio usually gives a bit more information.

Comment: The problem started happening when I started binding local folders and you're right, I am binding windows folder for Docker using WSL linux, but still can't figure out how to bypass that

Comment: Any errors in the output window in visual studio? Volume mounts should be no problem in WSL but need to be formatted correctly, eg: /c/Users/someuser/somefolder

Answer (score 0):

I have this issue when trying to start a project from within Visual Studio when it's not running in administrator mode. I always forget and end up with this error. Same goes for if I run "iotedgehubdev.exe setup" from a command prompt. It only works when the command prompt is running in administrator mode.

Comment: Well, it should work without admin privilege imo. I had problems with paths that's why it got stuck for me. Maybe that's also the case for you, anyway the @mawax answer is the best